# Two objects in a method from a class?

Tags: python, class, object

I'm having a small issue with this code, I am currently learning about classes and trying to separate the two objects I have created to use both of them in a method from the class.

```
import math

class Segment:

    def __init__(self, xcoord = 0, ycoord = 0):
        self.x = xcoord
        self.y = ycoord

    def get(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)

    def setx(self, xcoord):
        self.x = xcoord

    def sety(self, ycoord):
        self.y = ycoord

    def length(self, xcoord, ycoord):
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(xcoord-ycoord,2)+(xcoord-ycoord,2))

p1 = Segment(3,4)
p2 = Segment()
p2.setx(5)
p2.sety(5)
s = Segment(p1,p2)
print(Segment.get(p1))
print(Segment.get(p2))
print(s.length())
```

I know that I am missing parameters in my `length()` method, or perhaps I have not?  I would like to understand how I am able to have the objects interact with on another after I have defined them.

For further clarity, I am trying to print the distance between the two objects using the parameters I have assigned to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's forget the code for a second.  Firstly, let's talk about naming things.  Your `Segment` class is not a class of *segments* - it's a class of *points*.  So let's start by renaming your class `Point`.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, xcoord = 0, ycoord = 0):
        self.x = xcoord
        self.y = ycoord
```

Better already, no?

Now, imagine you're looking at someone else's code, trying to use that.  Their `Point`s have a `length()` method that you can call.  What do you expect that to do?  What could that... possibly do?  A number of things, all because `length` is an awful descriptor for something that a `Point` is doing.  It's certainly not a *property* of the `Point` - a point is 0-dimensional.

So let's rethink that function.  There are two obvious ways to make this API - your `Point` class could have a `distance_to(other_point)` method, that would accept one argument - another `Point`.  Optionally, you could have a module-level function `segment_length(point1, point2)` that would give you the length of the segment defined by the two `Point` objects.

So, the module-level function:

```
def segment_length(p1, p2):
   return math.sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)**2 + (p2.y-p1.y)**2)
```

I'll leave the `Point` method to you, should you wish to attempt it.  It looks very similar, just using `self` in lieu of one of the points.

Comment: Thank you for being straight with me, I took your advice and made the proper changes.  Thank you for teaching me.

Answer (score 1):

Lets walk through this:

- `p1` is an instance of the `Segment` class with attributes `x=3, y=4`.
- `p2` is an instance of the `Segment` class with attributes `x=0, y=0`,
- When you set `p2` to `(5, 5)` you could do it with `p2 = Segment(5, 5)`,
- `s` will have attributes `x=p1` (an instance of `Segment`, not a coordinate) and `y=p2` (another instance of `Segment`).

### Calculating the length.

Your `length` method should look like this:

```
def length(self, xcoord, ycoord):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(xcoord - self.x,2)+math.pow(ycoord - self.y,2))
```

This now uses the `x` and `y` coordinates of the class instance (in the example below, `p1`) and calculates the length between them, and the `xcoord` and `ycoord` parameters provided.

And you would call this with:

```
p2x, p2y = p2.get()
print(p1.length(p2x, p2y))
```

Comment: It gave me the same results both ways.

Comment: `Segment.get(p1)` is legal, it's equivalent to `p1.get()`, just with the `self` parameter passed explicitly, rather than being handled by Python's method binding machinery. It's probably not something you want to be calling, most of the time, but you can if you want to.

Comment: Ahh thank you @Blckknght - i'll amend my answer. Learn something new every day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're missing a second `math.pow()` in your line:

```
return math.sqrt(math.pow(xcoord-ycoord,2)+(xcoord-ycoord,2))
```

Secondly with your call `s = Segment(p1, p2)` the `x` and `y` values of your `Segment` `s` are equal to the segments `p1` and `p2`.

At the moment your values should read:

```
p1.get()
> (3, 4)
p2.get()
> (5, 5)
```

After the assignment of s you get:

```
s.get()
> ((3, 4), (5, 5))
```

This is problematic, because `math.pow()` has no idea what to do with a `Segment` object.